# Remove Bitbucket deployment from Azure Web App

Tags: git, azure, bitbucket

In trying to figure out the best way to deploy our website, initially we were using the deployment configured in Azure to check for new updates on our git repository, Bitbucket. However, we ended up using another tool from our buildserver and no longer need this integration.

I cannot find a way to remove the Bitbucket deployment as configured in Azure. Can anyone show me where this is?

Here is a screenshot of how the deployment appears in Azure for reference to what I'm referring:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find it in the dashboard tab on the right side:

[image]

PS: Not sure why they didn't put it under the deployments tab, but then again I never understood MS websites.

Comment: Thanks! I can spend so much time looking through the interface and not find it. This was indeed what I was looking for.